# How to write a function to convert double to char in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need a function `double2char` that will take in a `1 × N` double array and output a `1 × N` character array.

My desired outputs:

- `double2char(1)` should return `'a'`, `double2char(2)` should return `'b'`, ..., `double2char(26)` should return `'z'`
- `double2char([1 2 3])` should return `'abc'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do -

```
char(input_array+'a'-1)
```

Sample run -

```
>> input_array = [1,2,3];
>> char(input_array+'a'-1)
ans =
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check http://www.asciitable.com, you can see that ASCII code 65 matches 'A'. You can use MATLAB's `char()` to convert integers to characters or vectors of integers to strings.